# SIGABRT happens at the end of this function

Tags: objective-c

At the end of the following function (which is only called once), I receive a SIGABRT as a result of a __stack_chk_fail. I think it means the stack is corrupted? Why is it causing this abort?

The code is supposed to send a file to my server, and to do so it breaks up the file into 256 byte chunks and sends each individually. The reason I did this is just writing `[writeSock write:[buf bytes]]` resulted in only like 30-40% of the data being sent.

```
- (BOOL) sendFile:(NSData*)buf
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)(@"servername"), 999, &readStream, &writeStream);

    NSInputStream * readSock = (__bridge NSInputStream*)(readStream);
    [readSock setDelegate:self];
    NSOutputStream * writeSock = (__bridge NSOutputStream * )(writeStream);
    [writeSock setDelegate:self];


    [readSock scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [writeSock scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    NSLog(@"Open socket");
    [readSock open];
    [writeSock open];

    [writeSock write:(uint8_t*)("submit\0\0\0\0") maxLength:10];

    NSLog(@"Data length: %d", [buf length]);

    // Write length to server
    uint32_t length = (uint32_t)([buf length]);
    [writeSock write:(uint8_t *)&length maxLength:4];
    // Write data to server
    Byte smallBuf[256];
    uint32_t amountTransfered = 0;
    while (amountTransfered < length) {
        NSRange r;
        r.location = amountTransfered;
        r.length = MIN(amountTransfered + 256, length - amountTransfered);
        [buf getBytes:smallBuf range:r];
        [writeSock write:smallBuf maxLength:r.length];
        amountTransfered += r.length;
    }

    NSLog(@"Done writing");
    /*uint8_t inBuf[128];
    [readSock read:inBuf maxLength:128];

    if (strcmp((char*)inBuf, "success") != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't submit file: %s", (char*)inBuf);
    }*/

    NSLog(@"Close socket");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You should always check the result of `[NSOutputStream write:maxLength:]`, if it returns -1, you should not continue to write on `writeSock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

`r.length = MIN(amountTransfered + 256, length - amountTransfered);`

Did you mean:

`r.length = MIN(256, length - amountTransfered);`

?

Comment: I guess I managed to sometimes mix it up with "end" instead of "length", but sometimes get it right.